# Question on Supremum and Infimum Proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $y$ be a real number. Prove that $\sup(X)=y$ if and only if

1) $x$ is less than or equal to $y$ for every $x$ in $X$.

2) For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x$ in $X$ such that $y-\epsilon < x ≤ y$

I'm not sure how to prove this, I started off with just using the definition of a supremum and the completeness axiom but didn't get that far. I'm also not sure how how to deal with the inequality at the end. Any direction on where to go with this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: What is the set A? What is your definition of supremum?

Comment: I actually made a typo, let me fix it

Comment: What is c in your part two?

Comment: I think it's just a random element in X, I'm not entirely clear on that though.

Comment: These are defining properties of supremum.

Answer (score 0):

For part two, since $y$ is a supremum for $X$, $y-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $X$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Since $y - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound, there exists some $x \in X$ such that $y-\epsilon < x$.

Comment: The second and third occurrences of "a supremum" should be "an upper bound".

Comment: @AndreasBlass You are right. That is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If $y = \sup(X)$, then $y$ is an upperbound for $X$, so by definition $\forall x \in X: x \leq y$

(2) Suppose the statement is not true. Then, we have:

$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall x \in X: y - \epsilon \geq x > y$$

But then $y- \epsilon$ is an upperbound of $X$, but this is not possible because $y$ is the least upper bound of $X$.

Hence, we must have that:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists x \in X: y- \epsilon < x \leq y$$

Comment: I'm just slightly confused by the notation. You're using " : " as "such that" right? I've just never seen it used twice in a row like you have.

Comment: Yes, it means that. And it is not just me who uses this notation, but the entire mathematical world. For example, google epsilon-delta definition if you want to encounter even nastier things. Some people replace the : by , though, but I do not like this because , seems like you can interchange quantors, which you really can't. Other people omit both : and ,

Comment: Help! I've just been expelled from the entire mathematical world. (Fortunately, I still count as "other people".)